# QDockWidget is covered under main window after setFloating(true)

Tags: qt, qt5

I want a dock widget to be floating at the beggining. So I add dock widget to the area and then setFloating(true). But the behaviour is that this dock widget is cover under main window (wont stayin on top)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    auto* dock = new QDockWidget(this);
    auto* widget = new QWidget(dock);
    auto* layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    widget->setLayout(layout);
    dock->setWidget(widget);
    addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dock);
    dock->setFloating(true);


    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("test", this));
}
```

Dock widget is visible in the right top corner, but when I drag the main window, dock widget hides under it. To fix it I have to drag dock widget to the dock area, then I set it floating again, and this widget is on top.

How to force QDockWidget to be floating and on top at the beginning?

Qt Version 5.11.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Does [`dock->raise()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#raise) help?  Having said that I suspect you may be at the mercy of the window manager being used.

Comment: I have just tested this with both Windows and Ubuntu. On Windows it works as expected. On Ubuntu the behavior is different, exactly as you have described it. I would suggest you to report it as a bug to Qt.

Comment: @G.M. It wont help.

Comment: @scopchanov Reported

Comment: For what it's worth, the box I'm working at right now (Suse Linux with FVWM window manager) behaves as expected -- floating dock widget always on top of parent widget.  So I strongly suspect the problem you're seeing lies with your window manager and/or its configuration rather than `Qt`.

Comment: @G.M., could you please post a working example as an answer?

Comment: @G.M. But after I drag this to the dock area, or not set floating to true, it behaves as expected, so maybe there is any workaround?

Moreover the other properties of QDockWidget dont work properly. For example if I set allowed areas to top `setAllowedAreas(Qt::TopDockWidgetArea);`, it could be added to right area too until I dock it to the top. Then other areas are blocked.